# Emails sent from server

Tags: php, email, cpanel, spam, spf

I have a server setup with WHM / cPanel. I am about to launch a server so people can sign up and use my software to create websites & sell.

Most will be setup on a sub domain (user.mywebsite.com).

The issue I am having is emails sent from the server (like order notifications) going into spam because they are coming from an email address not owned by the domain. Example, someuser@gmail.com

In the cPanel account of the main domain on the server I have DKIM and SPF enabled. I tried to add gmail.com to the "Additional Hosts that send mail for your domains (A):" but it doesn't seem to save (not there after saving).

Another scenario is we have a contact form and when a visitor fills out the form it is sent from the visitor's email address to the website owner so that email address won't match either.

1) Is it possible to add gmail.com, yahoo.com, etc ... to the SPF records?

2) A better way to do this? Users will be signing up using their own email addresses so they won't be matching the domain.

Also tried sending "from" email@mywebsite.com and adding a "reply to" someuser@gmail.com but it didn't like that either (went to spam).

FYI SPF record currently is: v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:12.345.67.890 ~all

Comment: Sender Policy Framework wouldn't be very effective if you could spoof your unauthorized server as a sender for Yahoo or Gmail... A better solution would be to whitelist your own server when sending emails internally - but be warned that it's up to you to prevent spam from being sent through these contact forms. This only works if your clients are using email accounts hosted with you, of course.

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. This is more server configuration.

Comment: Agreed this is still off-topic. For the record, there's a _lot_ of websites and servers that do this (send email on behalf of a user filling in a contact form) and don't run into spam issues with Yahoo and Gmail. Make sure you're using proper honeypots and spam prevention techniques from the website side so your server doesn't get marked as a source of spam. Don't forget about Reverse PTR records and proper hostnames being set.